# npm unable to use installed package -- config

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs and npm.  I am trying to install config package as below.

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ sudo npm install config -g
config@1.15.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/node_modules/config
rvnath@rv ~/projects/bs/nodejs/siteright $
```

To test the config, I created a simple conftest.js file as below..

```
var conf = require('config');
console.log("conf got required.");
```

It throws up an error, indicating it can't find the module.

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ node conftest.js 
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rvnath/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright/conftest.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $
```

I can't understand what is going wrong here.

However if I run filetest.js (whose content is below), it works..

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ cat filetest.js 
var fs=require('fs');
console.log("fs got required");
```

The output in this case is...

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ node filetest.js 
fs got required
```

It seems builtin packages are working correctly, but the ones which I installed using sudo npm install are not.

To reinforce my understanding, I tried installing another module 'xml2js', which successfully installed, but jsontest.js failed. Here is the output for this..

xml2js installation output:

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ sudo npm install xml2js -g
xml2js@0.4.10 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/node_modules/xml2js
├── sax@1.1.1
└── xmlbuilder@2.6.4 (lodash@3.10.1)
```

jsontest.js:

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ cat jsontest.js 
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
console.log('xml2js got requried.');
```

test output:

```
rvnath@rv ~/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright $ node jsontest.js 
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'xml2js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rvnath/projects/mbs/nodejs/siteright/jsontest.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Comment: You shouldn't install your packages globally (`-g`).

Comment: read a thread about not installing packages globally and a counter argument which says that it leads to packages duplication. So not sure what to do :)

Comment: Perhaps [this npm FAQ](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#i-installed-something-globally-but-i-can-t-require-it) will help.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  And of course this blog, which I started reading now.  Where the author also lost sanity like mine... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm